# Viewing all available IPs in a Windows Phone app?

Tags: c#, list, networking, windows-phone-8, ip

I have previously asked this question but ran into difficulties in implementing the given answer.

I was told that the following code would do what I required (that was list all available IPs on the device that was running my app and display them as a list, allowing the user to choose one).

```
var  ips = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
           .Where(inf => inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
           .Where(inf => inf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
           .Select(x => new{
                name = x.Name,
                ips = x.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Select(y=>y.Address)
                      .ToList()
           })
           .ToList();
```

It now turns out most of this is not available to Windows Phone or Windows Store users.

I think what I need lies in the `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace but I can't pinpoint the exact method I'd need.

I do the same in Android and Apple which is fairly straightforward. An example of the Apple view is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;`**

```
var ips = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
            .Where(x => x.IPInformation != null)
            .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: how would I display the outcome of this in a list?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Have you tried anything? How about reading some docs?  (`listView1.ItemsSource = ips;`)